# Can we narrow down the site selection box on Careers in the Answer section?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

This isn't anything very important, but it's still annoying.

On Careers 2.0, in the Answers section, when you click add, a little box comes up with a site drop-down in the corner. This allows you to select the side from which you want to add answers. But when you open it, it shows *every single Stack Exchange site*, even the ones I don't have an account on:
[image: I don't have an account on most of these...]

When I select a site I don't have an account on, it gives the message:

> Sorry, you don't seem to have any answers on that site. Choose another.

Will someone change the dropdown to only show sites that the user has an account on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went ahead and made this change because it really does make it easier to find the sites you're looking for.  I am selecting only the accounts we know about on Careers in order to prevent adding another API call on every profile edit load.  There is one consequence of that where the situation could arise that you create a brand new account on a site, answer a question and then decide you want to add that answer to your profile before Careers has synced up to find out you have an account on that site.  I think the chance of this will be low enough (and we can force a resync in case of it ever happening) so this will be going out shortly.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response! You guys are awesome!